# How to detach and restore jQuery Mobile pages

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I am working on a jQuery Mobile app that has a known set of distinct thematic pages, e.g.:

```
<div id="theme1_page" data-role="page" class="ui-page" data-theme="c">
```

The pages have values I populate via a spatial query. I'd like the user to be able to choose which of the pages they see and restore or change their preference of visible pages at any time.

On a Settings panel I want to use a series of check boxes, e.g.:

```
$('input[id^="checkbox_"]').on( "change", function ()
```

To turn off a page via `detach()` rather than `hide()` or `remove()` (which cause other problems) and turn the page back on later or even in another session.

I want to store the state (on/off) and order of all pages for use at another time.

As I'm quite new to this, would placing the page into `localStorage` somehow be the means to keep track of things and then be the means to retrieve the page on demand to insert at the proper index?

How does one store each detached page’s values, events, position in the array of pages, and visible state?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to store it in a variable/namespace if you do not need to have it saved across sessions.

If you do need it saved across sessions, the. you'll definitely need localstorage or some way of keeping track of it server side either through the DB or the session object might be a good idea.

Localstorage is pretty much like namespacing , learn a bit more about it here : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp